# SqlDataReader - Populate child list with all the items that match

Tags: c#, wpf, many-to-many, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I am trying to populate parent objects with child object that match but cannot figure out how to only display the ones that match.
I manage to get the child objects and add them to the list but it displays all the child objects for the parent objects.

```
        public ObservableCollection<Book> GetBooks()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con.con;

            Book book = new Book();
            List<int> IdBooks=  new List<int>();
            List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT b.idBook,b.Title,b.Writer,t.IdTypeOfBook,t.Type FROM tblBook b LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTypeOfBook t ON b.idTypeOfBook = t.idTypeOfBook WHERE b.Active = 1 ORDER BY b.idBook";
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    var idBook = Convert.ToInt32(rd["IdBook"]);
                    var title = rd["Title"].ToString();
                    var writer = rd["Writer"].ToString();
                    var idType = Convert.ToInt32(rd["IdTypeOfBook"]);
                    var type = rd["Type"].ToString();

                    book = new Book()
                    {
                        IdBook = idBook,
                        Title = title
                    };

                    book.Tags = tags;
                    Books.Add(book);

                    IdBooks.Add(idBook);
                }
                rd.Close();
            }

            foreach (var idBook in IdBooks)
            {
                SqlCommand tagCommand = new SqlCommand();
                tagCommand.Connection = con.con;

                tagCommand.CommandText = "SELECT t.IdTag,t.Name FROM tblTag t LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBookTag bt ON bt.idTag = t.idTag WHERE bt.idBook = @ID";
                tagCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", idBook);


                SqlDataReader tagReader = tagCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (tagReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (tagReader.Read())
                    {
                        Tag tag = new Tag();
                        var idTag = Convert.ToInt32(tagReader["IdTag"]);
                        var name = tagReader["Name"].ToString();
                        tag.IdTag = idTag;
                        tag.Name = name;


                        tags.Add(tag);

                    }
                    tagReader.Close();
                }
            }


            con.Close();
            return Books;
        }
```

For now I only manage to display all the tags and not ones that match the book.

**EDIT**

This is how it looks right now

```
        public ObservableCollection<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con.con;

        Book book = new Book();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT b.idBook,b.Title,b.Writer,t.IdTypeOfBook,t.Type FROM tblBook b LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTypeOfBook t ON b.idTypeOfBook = t.idTypeOfBook WHERE b.Active = 1 ORDER BY b.idBook";
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                var idBook = Convert.ToInt32(rd["IdBook"]);
                var title = rd["Title"].ToString();
                var writer = rd["Writer"].ToString();
                var idType = Convert.ToInt32(rd["IdTypeOfBook"]);
                var type = rd["Type"].ToString();

                book = new Book()
                {
                    IdBook = idBook,
                    Title = title,
                    Tags = new List<Tag>()
                };

                Books.Add(book);
            }
            rd.Close();
        }

        foreach (var bk in Books)
        {
           book.Tags = GetTagsThatMatch(bk.IdBook);

        }
        con.Close();
        return Books;
    }


    public List<Tag> GetTagsThatMatch(int idBook)
    {

        SqlCommand tagCommand = new SqlCommand();
        tagCommand.Connection = con.con;

        tagCommand.CommandText = "SELECT t.IdTag,t.Name FROM tblTag t LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBookTag bt ON bt.idTag = t.idTag  WHERE bt.idBook = @ID";
        tagCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", idBook);


        SqlDataReader tagReader = tagCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (tagReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (tagReader.Read())
            {
                Tag tag = new Tag();
                var idTag = Convert.ToInt32(tagReader["IdTag"]);
                var name = tagReader["Name"].ToString();
                tag.IdTag = idTag;
                tag.Name = name;

                Console.WriteLine(tag.Name);
                Tags.Add(tag);

            }
            tagReader.Close();
        }

        return Tags;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a list of tags:

```
List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
```

Then for every book, you're setting the `Tags` property to that list.

```
book.Tags = tags;
Books.Add(book);
```

This is significant because that means that regardless of how many books you have, there is only one list of tags. The `Tags` property of each book refers to the same list of tags. They're all sharing it.

That means that in the second query, when you add tags to this list:

```
tags.Add(tag);
```

...you're adding that tag to every book. The result is that every single book is going to have the same tags, because there's only one list.

What you probably want is to just add the tags to the books they go with. To do that, instead of creating one list of tags, do this:

```
book = new Book()
    {
        IdBook = idBook,
        Title = title,
        Tags = new List<Tag>()
    };
```

Now every book will have its own list of tags. You can add tags to one book without adding them to all books.

You can discard the `tags` variable and `IdBooks`. You don't need to build a list of book IDs because you've already created a list of books, and each book already has an ID.

So you can replace the second part of the method with this:

```
        foreach (var book in Books) // loop through the books, not the IDs
        {
            SqlCommand tagCommand = new SqlCommand();
            tagCommand.Connection = con.con;

            // in your query, get the ID from the book
            tagCommand.CommandText = "SELECT t.IdTag,t.Name FROM tblTag t LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBookTag bt ON bt.idTag = t.idTag WHERE bt.idBook = @ID";
            tagCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", book.IdBook);


            SqlDataReader tagReader = tagCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (tagReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (tagReader.Read())
                {
                    Tag tag = new Tag();
                    var idTag = Convert.ToInt32(tagReader["IdTag"]);
                    var name = tagReader["Name"].ToString();
                    tag.IdTag = idTag;
                    tag.Name = name;

                    // Add the tag to the collection of tags for just that one book.
                    book.Tags.Add(tag);

                }
                tagReader.Close();
            }
        }
```

---

To make this easier to debug, I'd also consider putting the part that gets tags in a separate function like this:

```
List<Tag> GetTags(int bookId)
```

and moving the code that looks up the tags for each book there. That way your main function will look like this:

```
foreach(var book in Books)
{
    book.Tags = GetTags(book.IdBook);
}
```

It looks like just moving code around, but it's going to result in smaller functions that are easier to read. When you move the code you might realize that you're using some variable you didn't think you were using, and that will help you catch a problem.

That way if the part that's giving you trouble is the function that gets the tags for a book, now you can test it separately by calling it with just one book ID and seeing what you get back. If you get the wrong result then you can debug the method using just one book ID.

Debugging is easier when we can work with smaller pieces of code. If we know that one part works we can stop looking at it or running it over again and just look at the part that isn't working.

---

Update 2 (sorry, this has gone way past the point where this is useful to anyone else who reads this, but there's no turning back now.)

Change this:

```
    foreach (var bk in Books)
    {
       book.Tags = GetTagsThatMatch(bk.IdBook);
    }
```

to this:

```
    foreach (var bk in Books)
    {
       bk.Tags = GetTagsThatMatch(bk.IdBook);
    }
```

If you add the tags to `book` then you're adding them to the last book created, not to the current book in the `foreach` loop.

To avoid this confusion. delete this line:

```
   Book book = new Book();
```

and declare the variable right where you're using it:

```
Book book = new Book()
    {
        IdBook = idBook,
        Title = title,
        Tags = new List<Tag>()
    };
```

By declaring the variable inside the scope of that loop, it becomes impossible to accidentally use it outside of that scope. It's helpful to keep variables in the smallest scope possible.

Comment: I tried it and now it displays all the tags for the last book

Comment: Check your 2nd SQL query and make sure that as you're looping through all of the books you're using the ID for each different book in your query. And run that query separately to make sure it's correct. I looked at the code but I didn't examine the queries so much.

Comment: It loops through them it seems fine I will try to see if I can figure it out

Comment: the query seems fine I don't know how else could I write it, I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: I added some updates. I can't see what's happening in your code, but if if you break it up into some smaller pieces it will be easier to separate the part that works from the part that doesn't work. It's way easier to spot the error in a smaller method.

Comment: Try to just write a function that just takes a book ID and returns a `List<Tag>`. Test and debug just that function by itself. Just one book ID. Test the query in SQL before you put it in your code. If it doesn't work in SQL, fix the query first. If it works in SQL, it will be much easier to fix that one function by itself. It sounds like that query or method is where the problem is. What's difficult is that I saw one issue in the code, but now as your code changes there's no way to see its current state. (If you change the code in the question the existing answer won't make sense any more.)

Comment: It seems to be fine in getting them but adding them to the right book seems to be the problem

Comment: I think its the method I tested the query in MSSQL with one book ID and it returns it correctly and also in the method it just always adds it to the last one. Added in edit how it looks now.

Comment: If the trouble is getting them to go with the right book, create a function like this: `void AddTagsToBook(Book book)`. Pass an individual book to that function. Now there's no books, only one single book. It will be impossible to add tags to the wrong book.

Comment: Change `book.Tags = GetTagsThatMatch(bk.IdBook);` to `bk.Tags = GetTagsThatMatch(bk.IdBook);` `book` is the last book you created. `bk` is the book in the loop. To make it easier, declare `book` inside the loop where it's created. That way the variable won't even be available outside the loop to accidentally use. Making a variable available in a smaller scope reduces the risk of using where you didn't mean to.

Comment: I did this 
        public void AddTagsToBook(Book book)
        {
                book.Tags = GetTagsThatMatch(1);
        } still adds only to the last one

Comment: Look at the previous message. That's where the bug was. You have two variables - `book` and `bk`. You meant to add the tags to `bk` but you were adding them to `book`.